# How to set an icon's color to [default color] in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

An icon has a default color, and it could be different under different themes.

When meet the condition, I hope the icon's color become `Color.RED`, otherwise it used the default color (example, `white` on one theme and `yellow` on another theme)

But I don't know the grammar of how to set to `default color`. Please help, thanks a lot!

```
val judge = ... //a mutableStateOf Boolean
...
// how to set [default color]?
Icon(painterResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_error_outline_24), 
    contentDescription = null, 
    tint = if (judge) Color.RED else [default color])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to `Icon` file you see its value:

```
tint: Color = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current)
```

You can just set it again

Comment: How do we know what the current is?

Answer (score 6):

In Compose Material 1.3.1, the source code to change the tint of icon is:

`val colorFilter = if (tint == Color.Unspecified) null else ColorFilter.tint(tint)`

So just pass the Color.Unspecified to Icon's tint param will keep the default tint color of icon:

```
 Icon(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.your_icon),
    contentDescription = null,
    tint = Color.Unspecified
 )
```